# Difference Between Flashing Drain and On-Grade Drain?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, drains

What is the difference between an "on-grade" drain and a "flashing" drain? What situations call for which? If installing a basement floor drain, which should I use?

In case it's not clear, here are the items I'm researching:

[On-Grade Drains](http://www.siouxchief.com/products/drainage/commercial/on-grade-drains/finishline/pvc-abs-sch--40-hub-connection/6-1-2-tops)

[image: On-Grade Drain]

---

[Flashing Drains](http://www.siouxchief.com/products/drainage/commercial/flashing-drains/finishline/sch--40-hub-connection/6-1-2-tops)

[image: Flashing Drain]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the [brochure](http://www.siouxchief.com/docs/default-source/print/print-brochures/drainage/finishline-brochure.pdf?sfvrsn=12), its all in there.

> ### On-Grade Drains
>
> on-grade floor drains are for use in
> ground-level applications, or where a waterproofing
> membrane is not needed.
>
> ### Flashing Drains
>
> Flashing drains are typically installed when
> a waterproofing membrane is used to protect finished
> areas under the drain.

you are going to want an on grade drain for almost all basement slab applications

Comment: Any idea what it means when the pipe width is quoted as 3" x 4" instead of a single number? I would think this implies a coupling that converts from one size to another, but I don't see that on these drains...

Comment: Like toilet flanges, they will fit on the outside of a 3" pipe and on the inside of a 4" pipe.